Возможно ли через Telegram API добавить человека в чат?
написал скрипт, который автоматизирует добавление людей в чат из базы данных по юзернейму. В целом, он работает, но только при условии, что мы с человеком добавили друг друга в контакты. Если мы не являемся взаимными контактами, скрипт выводит ошибку в терминале о том, что человек не является взаимным контактом. Возможно ли это как-то обойти?
Заранее спасибо!
